# call two file from another with node js

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, node.js

I have a file called node.js:

```
var net = require('net');

var crypto = require('crypto');

//sjcl
var sjcl = require('./sjcl');

//retrive fb profile
var loadFb = require('./loadFb.js');
var loadFeed = require('./loadFeed.js');

//read json user file
var fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/users','utf8');

var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 7000;

net.createServer(function(sock) {

    // We have a connection - a socket object
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log('User request profile of: ' + data);
        //var date = (data.toString()).split("***");
        //var from = date[1];

        loadFb(extendetPath, function(pageData) 
        {

          loadFeed(extendetPath2, function(pageData2) 
          {

            var fs = require('fs');
            var profileText = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/profile','utf8');
            console.log(profileText);
            sock.write(profileText);


          });

        });
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);

function returnKeyFromUser(id)
{
  //text
  var trovata = false;
  var dati = JSON.parse(text);
  for(var i=0; i<dati.friendlist.friend.length && trovata==false; i++)
  {
    var user = (dati.friendlist.friend[i].username).replace("\n","");
    var userID = (id).replace("\n","");
    if(user==userID)
    {
      trovata=true;
      return ((dati.friendlist.friend[i].publicKey).toString()).replace("\n","");
    }
  }
  if(trovata==false)
    return null;
}
```

There is a small http server that receives a facebook username and what he have to do is retrieve 2 page:

a graphapi with the profile information, and a graphapi with the feed informations of a facebook profile
I copy the other two files:

```
var https = require('https');

module.exports = function(path, callback) {
  var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: (path.toString()).replace("\n",""),
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var req = https.get(options, function(res) {

    var pageData = "";

if((path.toString()).indexOf("/")==0 && (path.toString()).indexOf("/GET /`HTTP/")!=0) 
//for load only (I hope facebook profile)

    {

      console.log(options);

      res.setEncoding('utf8');

      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        pageData += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function()
      {       

          var fs = require('fs');
          fs.writeFile("/tmp/profile", pageData, function(err) {
          if(err) {
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              console.log("The file was saved!");
          }
         });

        //callback(pageData);
        return;

      });
    }
  });
};
```

3° file

```
var https = require('https');

module.exports = function(path, callback) {
  var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: (path.toString()).replace("\n",""),
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var req = https.get(options, function(res) {

    var pageData = "";

    if((path.toString()).indexOf("/")==0 && (path.toString()).indexOf("/GET / HTTP/")!=0) //for load only (I hope facebook profile)
    {

      console.log(options);

      res.setEncoding('utf8');

      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        pageData += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function()
      {       

          var fs = require('fs');
          fs.appendFile('/tmp/profile', "***"+pageData, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('It\'s saved!');

          });
          callback(pageData);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

I don't know If there is a way to call the two file in the first file node.js but what I done is this: (to call from node.js the fist file, and from the second file call the third)
in node.js file I call the first file loadFb.js with this command:

```
loadFb(extendetPath, function(pageData) 
{
```

This call saves a file on my tmp profile directory and inside I call the other file loadFeed  that appends some text.

After that I have to send the entire information to the client but I have a mistake.
In order the nodejs correctly call loadFb  and he write tmp - profile, than he call loadFeed
but before appending the information the node  call back to the client only the half of informations that I need.
I'm not a good nodejs programmer, this is a work for my thesis.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the following code:

```
  res.on('end', function()
  {       

      var fs = require('fs');
      fs.appendFile('/tmp/profile', "***"+pageData, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved!');

      });
      callback(pageData);
  });
```

What it does it runs the **asynchronous** method `appendFile` and immediately after that calls `callback`. So when the code in the callback is executed, the file is not updated yet. You need to move the `callback(pageData);` to the `appendFile`'s callback. And you need to review you code keeping this in mind because I see that the same fix should be made in another file so maybe there are some similar places as well.